# Execute an insert query include date into access by python

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to execute a query to insert two values into a simple table in an access database.  But I got this error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft
> Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. (-3502)(SQLExecDirectW)')

How should I write the date format? My code is like below (The code is working with only integers to insert so I think my date format is no correct):

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\behdad\Documents\Database1.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("insert into Table1 (date, number) VALUES( '2021-02-05 00:00:00', 24)")
```

The sample table is here:
[date format in access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEKM3.png)

Comment: Try using `#` instead `'` for delimiters. Date is a reserved word. Advise not to use reserved words as field names. If still have an issue, try `[date]`.

Comment: I do these tricks but it still has errors

Comment: Thanks. It's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` and `number` are both [reserved words in Access SQL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sql-reserved-words-b899948b-0e1c-4b56-9622-a03f8f07cfc8), so if you have columns with those names you will need to enclose the names in square brackets:

```py
cursor.execute("insert into Table1 ([date], [number]) VALUES( '2021-02-05 00:00:00', 24)")
```